# Can we check Firestore reads origin?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to quantify how many Firestore reads come from clients and how many from Google Cloud Functions?
I'd like to reduce my project reads costs.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase currently does not provide tools to track the origin of document reads. All the **reads** fall under the same bucket, which is: "*Read happened*". If you need to measure specific reads from your app, you will have to track that yourself somehow. You can add a logger to your app which will track if the request came from the client or just the Cloud Function itself.
This [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs) may come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Firestore audit logging information
>
> Google Cloud services write audit logs to help you answer the
> questions, "Who did what, where, and when?" within your Google Cloud
> resources.
>
> #### Data Access audit logs
>
> Includes "admin read" operations that read metadata or configuration
> information. Also includes "data read" and "data write" operations
> that read or write user-provided data.
>
> To receive Data Access audit logs, you must explicitly enable them.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging